# Displaying image when a button is tapped ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I have 3 buttons representing 3 different images. An image will be displayed whenever its button is tapped. My question is, how to use if() and NSArray/NSMutableDictionary/UIButton tag or other method to make the codes shorter.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    _button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    _button1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 250, 50, 50);
     [_button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button1Tapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:_button1];

    _button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    _button2.frame = CGRectMake(140, 250, 50, 50);
    [_button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(button2Tapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:_button2];

    _button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    _button3.frame = CGRectMake(210, 250, 50, 50);
    [_button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(button3Tapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:_button3];
}

- (void)button1Tapped
{ 
    UIImage *_image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE_1"];
    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_image];
    _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 256, 384);        
    [self addSubview:_imageView];
}

- (void)button2Tapped
{ 
    UIImage *_image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE_2"];
    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_image];
    _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 256, 384);        
    [self addSubview:_imageView];
}

- (void)button3Tapped
{ 
    UIImage *_image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE_3"];
    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_image];
    _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 256, 384);        
    [self addSubview:_imageView];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Huh, it's refactoring day today. Just answered a similar one like 10 minutes ago.

Comment: BTW: use an array to store the buttons, then **do use** the `sender` argument of the action methods.

Comment: @H2CO3 thanks for the insight. Your refactoring answer is very helpful to the other part of my codes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup an array of images like this.  Make it a property in your class.  Also, build your image view early, too.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *images;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self.images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE_1"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE_2"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE_3"], nil];

    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self.images objectAtIndex:0]];
    _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 256, 384);        
    [self addSubview:_imageView];
}
```

When creating the buttons, give them tags like this...

```
_button1.tag = 1;
_button2.tag = 2;
_button3.tag = 3;
```

Also when creating the buttons, have them all use the same selector on tap...

```
 [_button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [_button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
// etc
```

On the tap, the tag-1 is going to be the array index...

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender {

    NSUInteger tag = ((UIButton *)sender).tag;
    UIImage *image = [self.images objectAtIndex:tag];
    self.imageView.image = image;
}
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much. Never thought would get an answer within hours!

Comment: i have to replace `sender.tag` with `[sender tag]` to make it work. Aren't they the same?

Comment: Yes.  That's the same. It's because the type is generic id type. I edited to show more correct syntax.